# Are Previous Microsoft SQL Installations Needed After SQL 2012 Upgrade?

Tags: sql-server, sql, installation

Are the older installations of Microsoft SQL Server needed after you installed Server 2012?
I've been doing some cleaning and noticed I've a whole list of SQL Server installation.

When I installed Server 2012, I clicked the upgrading option but previous versions are still present. I'm guessing they are needed but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard question. Many of us keep the older instance running for some reason or another.

The safe path is, when done with the older stuff, to:

1) Stop and disable the services from the older version
2) Check the search path for the OS, make sure it just references the new SQL Server

That said, I expect it is safe to uninstall the older SQL versions.

Comment: @reaper_unique, it is ok to vote for answers that are useful.

Comment: I need 15 points for that, and I don't have that yet on serverfault ;)